# Can we save time for repeated linear solves with the same linear operator?

Tags: matrices, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

I have a large collection vectors $(b_k)_{k\in K}$ for which I need to solve the linear system

$$\text{Find}\;\;x_k\;\;\text{such that}\;\;Ax_k=b_k.$$

For each $k$, $b_k$ is only available after computing $b_{k-1}$. The dimension of my problem is far too large to store $A$ and invert it. However:

1. $A$ is positive semidefinite
2. I have a function for computing the matrix-vector product of $A$ (i.e. given $x$, it computes $Ax$ by going through a linear process, but without storing $A$).

I know this sort of thing can be solved using only a matrix-vector product with Krylov methods like <s>GMRES</s> CG or MINRES . However, my understanding is that I would have to restart the Krylov method for every single $(b_k)_{k\in K}$. Is there a way to save time for this sort of repeated computation?

Comment: You could use the formulas of BFGS to compute a low-rank approximation of the inverse of $A$. This of course works best if the $b_k$ actually are clustered around some low-dimensional subspace, and may fail almost completely if that is not the case.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Thanks, and that's good to know -- but I don't think the $b_k$s have this property for my problem.

Comment: You may look into block Krylov methods. I'm not sure how active this area is at the moment, but there is a fair amount of literature on this exact problem. http://www.sam.math.ethz.ch/~mhg/pub/delhipap.pdf. It may also work to use the solution $x_k$ as the initial guess for $b_{k+1}$. http://dodo.inm.ras.ru/vassilevski/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/jcp219_210-227.pdf

Comment: I'm not sure how big the matrix is, but if the dominant cost is the matrix vector product, then block Krylov methods, which can take advantage of BLAS3, could speed things up considerably. Also, since your matrix is positive semidefinite, CG or MINRES are probably better choices that GMRES.

Comment: It is relevant to know if your $b_k$ are known from the start of if they become available one by one or in groups. It is not uncommon that $b_{k+1}$  a function of $x_k$. It is possible to recycle the subspace that you have already constructed to accelerate the next solve, the keyword is subspace recycling.

Comment: @tch Thanks for the suggestions, I shall look into those methods! Yes, I believe that the dominant cost would be requiring multiple matrix-vector products for each application of a Krylov method.

Comment: @CarlChristian Thank you very much -- yes, I should have mentioned that the $b_k$'s only become available in-sequence. I have amended the question to reflect this as well.

Comment: You could also use $LU$  factorization, takes $O(n^2)$ time, which better than $O(n^3)$ Gaussian elimination, I guess caching is sufficient for your problem.

Comment: @4.Pi.n unfortunately, as stated in the problem, I do not have the storage space for $A$, so I wouldn't be able to store a factorization of $A$ like LU or Cholesky.